# Circle passing through two points and tangent to a line

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, analytic-geometry

> "Find the equation of the circle passing through the origin $(0,0)$, the point $(1,0)$ and tangent to the line $x-2y+1=0$."

What I have done:

The equation of a circle with radius $R$ and center $(x_0,y_0)$ is $(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=R^2$. Since the circle passes through $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ it must be $$\tag{1}  x_0^2+y_0^2=R^2$$ $$ \tag{2} (1-x_0)^2+y_0^2=R^2$$ and since it is tangent to the line $x-2y+1=0$ the distance from the center to this line must equal the radius $R$ hence (using the fact that the distance $d$ from a point $(x_0,y_0)$ to a line $ax+by+c=0$ is $d=\frac{|ax_0+by_0+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$) we have  $$R=\frac{|ax_0+by_0+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\frac{|1x_0-2y_0+1|}{\sqrt{1^2+(-2)^2}}=\frac{|x_0-2y_0+1|}{\sqrt{5}} \tag{3}$$

From (1) and (2) we have

$$x_0^2 + y_0^2 = (1 - x_0)^2 + y_0^2 \Rightarrow x_0 = \dfrac{1}{2} \tag{4}$$

Equating (1) , (3) and (4) we have

$$\dfrac{1}{4}+y_0^2 = \dfrac{(\frac{3}{2}-2y_0)^2}{5} \Rightarrow y_0 = -3 \pm \sqrt{10}$$

So there are two solutions,

$$R^2 = \dfrac{1}{4}+(-3+\sqrt{10})^2 \Rightarrow (x - \dfrac{1}{4})^2+(y + 3 - \sqrt{10})^2 = \dfrac{1}{4} + (-3 + \sqrt{10})^2$$

and

$$R^2 = \frac{1}{4} + (-3 - \sqrt{10})^2 \Rightarrow (x - \frac{1}{4})^2 + (y + 3 + \sqrt{10})^2 = \dfrac{1}{4} + (-3 - \sqrt{10})^2$$.

Now, when I plot these solutions they appear to be wrong, so I would like to know which mistake(s) I have made.

[image: WolframAlpha plot of circle]

Comment: I don't know why but the LaTeX typesetting system is not working well at the end of the question.

Comment: The latex formatting is horrendous.  I'll try to fix it.

Comment: @Buraian thank you very much.

Comment: There will be two solutions. Nothing wrong in that

Comment: @Maverick thank you for your interest in my question; yes, but these two solutions also appear to be wrong...

Comment: Wrong according to what? @lorenzo What is the right solution then?

Comment: There are two solutions

Comment: @Buraian if you plot the two circles and the line they are not tangent, but they intersect in two points and it appers also that the circles do not pass through $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ as they should

Comment: What plotter are you using? @lorenzo

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/m2wgn4lp8h

Comment: Did you perhaps forget to take the square root of $R^2$?

Comment: Oh I found the mistake, see your x center you've taken in the wolfram plot. You've taken x=1/4 instead of x=1/2

Comment: @Buraian Ahhh, such a stupid mistake, thank you and all the other users for your help. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I plotted it on desmos, your answer does seem right. Here is the [link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jhis1vrn0m)

[image]
The idea is that the point on which the circle touches the line can be varied. This leads to two circles satisfying the other two constraints of passing through the given points.

The mistake in OP's plot: They put $x=1/4$ instead of $x=1/2$

Answer (score 2):

There is a very neat way of doing it if you are familiar with the idea of family of circles.

Equation of family of circles passing through $O(0, 0)$ and $A(1, 0)$ is given by
$$(x-0)(x-1)+(y-0)(y-0)+ky=0$$
where k is the parameter.

On simplification we get

$x^2+y^2-x+ky=0$

So the centre of above circle is $\left(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{k}{2}\right)$ and radius is $\frac{\sqrt{1+k^2}}{2}$

Since the line $x-2y+1=0$ is tangent to above circle so perpendicular dropped from centre to the line must be equal to the radius of the circle

$$\frac{\sqrt{1+k^2}}{2}=\frac{|1-2(-\frac{k}{2})+1|}{\sqrt{1^2+2^2}}$$

Solving for k we get $k=8\pm5\sqrt3$

Comment: I think I got the method, but one question, what is the motivation behind adding $ky$ in the equation? why not some term in x?

Comment: @Maverick neat! Thank you!

Comment: @Buraian  Equation of family of circles through $A(x_{1},y_{1})$ and $B(x_{2},y_{2})$ is given by $(x-x_{1})(x-x_{2})+(y-y_{1})(y-y_{2})+k(Equation of line AB)=0$